# displaying read more option when user enters large amount of data in richtextbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a richtextbox and a gridview.

When I enter the data into the richtextbox, it should be displayed in a gridview and saved in database.

Now my requirement is that, if i am entering a paragraph or a large amount of data I should display a "readmore" button, that when clicked, display the complete data.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="FreeTextBox" Namespace="FreeTextBoxControls" TagPrefix="FTB" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    <title>Richtextbox Sample</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validate() {
            var doc = document.getElementById('FreeTextBox1');
            if (doc.value.length == 0) {
                alert('Please Enter data in Richtextbox');
                return false;
            }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <FTB:FreeTextBox ID="FreeTextBox1" runat="server">
                            </FTB:FreeTextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvdetails" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RichtextBoxData">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lbltxt" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("RichtextData") %>'/>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClientClick="return validate()"
            Text="Submit" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lbltxt" runat="server"/>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

c# code-

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SureshDasari;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=MySampleDB");

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        BindGridview();
}

protected void BindGridview()
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select RichTextData from RichTextBoxData", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    gvdetails.DataSource = ds;
    gvdetails.DataBind();
}

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into RichTextBoxData(RichTextData) values(@Richtextbox)", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Richtextbox", FreeTextBox1.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    FreeTextBox1.Text = "";
    BindGridview();
}
```

Comment: This is not related to sql-server, please use tags properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first in your select query add id of your text(your primary key of table RichTextBoxData)
and in gridview  make it,s visible =false like this

```
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="id" InsertVisible="False" Visible="False">

        <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("id") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

and then

```
    protected void gvdetails_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {


            Label lb =e.Row.FindControl("lbltxt") as Label;

            if (lb.Text.Length > 15)//any length u want
            {

                DataRow drv = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;

                int tempID = Convert.ToInt32(drv["id"].ToString());

                HyperLink hp = new HyperLink();
                hp.Text = "read more";
                hp.NavigateUrl = "~/mydetails.aspx?id=" + tempID;
               e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Add(hp);
              lb.Text = lb.Text.Substring(0, 15);


            }

        }
    }
```

and on page_load of  mydetails.aspx  make 
query to select RichTextData where id=request.querystring["id"]

Comment: How can we save the data entered into the richtextbox to the folder that is selected by the user that is when i click on save the data should be saved in the folder selected by the user.